# Realm XCFramework nested in another XCFramework error

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use a XCFramework built with a private pod, that have another public dependencies inside. In that dependencies, all of them seem to work fine, except RealmSwift. When I try to import the XCFramework I built in my class, the following errors appear:

- 'RealmSwiftObject' is not a member type of struct 'RealmSwift.Realm'
- 'RealmSwiftObject' is not a member type of struct 'RealmSwift.Realm'
- 'RealmSwiftObject' is not a member type of struct 'RealmSwift.Realm'
- Type 'Element' does not conform to protocol 'RealmCollectionValue'
- 'RealmSwiftObject' is not a member type of struct
  'RealmSwift.Realm'
- 'RealmSwiftObject' is not a member type of struct 'RealmSwift.Realm'
- 'RealmSwiftObject' is not a member type of struct 'RealmSwift.Realm'
- 'RealmSwiftObject' is not a member type of struct 'RealmSwift.Realm'

I have been searching but I don't know why this error is showing because it doesn't seem like it has anything related to my problem, but I ran out of ideas.

I have tried install Realm both by Cocoapods and XCFramework. Same result

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).